# How to combine 3 histograms into 1 graph in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I am currently trying to combine 3 histogram distributions into 1 graph in Tableau. I am able to combine 2 histograms using Dual Axis but any one know how to combine 3?

I apologise for not being able to provide more info on the dataset because of information sensitivity.

Any help is appreciated!!

Thank you

[image]

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? It is not obvious that combining histograms works on a single chart.

Comment: You can have 3 measurement but it will be 3 lines and each line will have their own color

Comment: Read the help to learn how to use Measure Values and Measure Names placeholder fields, along the Measures shelf

Comment: I fear you have to restructure your data to long format, in order to combine the charts into one

Comment: Can you show me your data structure, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the left axis, when you hover the corner, it will allow you to drag and drop to the next chart which will combine views.